# Get Table Contents using HTML

Tags: java, html, jsp

```
<Table>
<tr>

<td>ID</td>
<td>NAME</td>
<td>MARKS</td>
<td>Grade</td>
<td><a href="AddRecord.jsp" >Update Record</a> </td>

</tr>
</Table>
```

How can I get table contents for modification, when I press Update hyperlink button? or how can I send these contents as a parameter to the page "AddRecord.asp".

Comment: If i provide you a code example, for HTML, Servlet and how to inturn provide the values to the new page. Will you be able to understand that. Since it's a huge coding part, that's why i asked before submitting it as my answer. Hope you knew the working of a Servlet thingy. Regards

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to submit a new row to a data table it sounds to me like you just need to use a traditional `<form>` and make the "Update Record" a submit type button. You are going to have to read up on using databases and JSP to process your update requests.

I suggest you start by reading on submitting forms at: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp

Comment: BTW +1 for suggesting an HTML `form`. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your best best is AJAX and JavaScript.  Make an AJAX call to get the content and add it to the DOM using JavaScript.

Comment: But dear , any html solution Without javascript or ajax?