# Assign variable to the value in HTML

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

```
String registration="10-120";
<input type="text" name="registrationUpdate" value="Reg#" maxlength="50" /><br>
```

In the above , `value="Reg#"` which is hard code. 
I want to assign **variable**  to the value. i.e. Means value=registration;

update me!

Comment: When you say you want to assign a variable are you talking about trying to access the value of the input with javascript?

Comment: Be more specific. What do you mean "assign **variable** to the value" and in what Servlet, JSP or something else?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Table Contents using HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8626625/get-table-contents-using-html).  This post provides no useful information that is not already in your (linked) prior post.  At least it is no more clear.

Comment: BTW - Would the *up-voter* care to share their reasoning?  I added a -1 (for a poorly researched, poorly expressed, possible duplicate) to balance it.

Comment: I edit my question, my be it clear all my scenario that I want to discuss

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your question is not very clear. I'll assume the variable is declared inside a servlet, because it's bad practice to use Java in a JSP. To be able to share a variable between a Servlet whic forwards to a JSP, you need to set this variable into a request attribute:

```
String registration = "10-120";
request.setAttribute("registration", registration);
```

And then in the JSP, you can get the value of the "registration" attribute using the JSP EL:

```
<input type="text" name="registrationUpdate" value="${registration}" maxlength="50" />
```

You should read the Java EE tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnadp.html

Answer (score 2):

itz very simple

```
    <% String registration="10-120"; %>
    <input type="text" name="registrationUpdate" value="<%=registration%>" maxlength="50" />
```

hope this will help you