# Assigning a value within the jsp expression tag to the angularjs model

Tags: angularjs, jsp

I'm stuck in a situation, where it is supposed to retrieve the id value stored in the session in the 'jsp' file and hence to assign the retrieved value to the angular var.

`<%=uidfrmSession%>` contains the retrieved value. But I can not find the way to assign it to the angular model.

Below is the approach I came up with, but it doesn't work.

```
 <input type="hidden" ng-value="<%=uidfrmSession %>" ng-model="uid">
```

When I check the angular model var `uid`'s value, it has `undefined` in it.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is probably that when angularJS is initially being loaded, the JSP hasn't yet updated the value for the item. I can think of 2 ways to solve this.

**OPTION 1**
Watch the model `uid` for changes, and then perform any extra functions after its value has been updated.

```
$scope.$watch('uid', function (nv, ov) {
  if (!nv) {
    return;
  }
  // Do whatever you need with the date for $scope.uid
  ...
}
```

**OPTION 2**
It's apparently best practice to avoid using `$watch` as much as possible and you can instead add `ng-change` to your `input` tag. So when the value of the model `uid` changes, whatever function you'll have assigned to `ng-change` will be called

// html

```
<input type="hidden" ng-change="doStuff()" ng-model="uid">
```

// code

```
$scope.doStuff = function () {
  // Do whatever you want with the value of $scope.uid
  ...
};
```

Cheers

Comment: Thank you for your concern Sylval D Ash..   But my problem is that i need the value acquired in the 'jsp' to be loaded in 'angular' so that i can have my further processing stuffs based on that value..

can u please suggest me some ideas  to that..

Comment: @Nishi sorry for that. I misunderstood your question. Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8631481/assign-variable-to-the-value-in-html) I hope it can provide you with the help you want

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work

```
<input type="hidden" ng-init="uid = '<%= uidfrmSession %>'">
```

**note:** we have to initialize the model, as default the value of model is undefined so it sets the value to undefined